# Construct lineString from points in mysql

Tags: mysql, spatial-query, mysql-spatial

Giving the following table (Position)

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| position_id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vehicle_id         | int(11) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| location           | point               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gps_time           | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to construct a lineString from the points which is location column to calculate the distance.

How to construct lineString from location column ?
Something like

```
select vehicle_id, lineString(location) from position group by vehicle_id order by gps_time;
```

Here is the data

```
select position_id,vehicle_id,astext(location),gps_time from position order by gps_time;

+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| position_id | vehicle_id | astext(location)            | gps_time            |
+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
|           3 |          1 | POINT(44.23912 15.307647)   | 2014-11-23 06:02:17 |
|           2 |          1 | POINT(44.240063 15.307788)  | 2014-11-23 08:54:11 |
|           1 |          1 | POINT(44.23884 15.307585)   | 2014-11-23 11:50:10 |
|           4 |          1 | POINT(44.232296 15.304604)  | 2014-11-24 07:24:29 |
|           5 |          1 | POINT(44.2332 15.304803)    | 2014-11-24 07:24:39 |
|           6 |          1 | POINT(44.2332 15.304803)    | 2014-11-24 07:24:49 |
|           7 |          1 | POINT(44.23428 15.3052)     | 2014-11-24 07:24:59 |
+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to calculate the distance between the points during specific gps_time.
That is the distance between point of position_id=3 and the point of position_id=2 then the result will be calculated with distance between point of position_id=2 and point of position_id=1 and so on.

Expected Result like:

```
+------------+------------- +--------------------+---------------------+
| vehicle_id | distance(km) | start_time         | end_time            |
+------------+------------- +--------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |          1.2 |2014-11-23 06:02:17 | 2014-11-24 07:24:59 |
+------------+------------- +--------------------+---------------------+
```

distance value (1.2) is just a random value from my mind. it should be calculated from previous points.

Comment: give some example data with the expected output.

Comment: Check my answer to your question Mr. @AbhikChakraborty